# Converter Várias páginas HTML para PDF

Tags: php

Estou a converter html para pdf utilizando o [html2pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf.git).
Porém com o aumento da quantidade de páginas essa conversão demora muito.
No meu caso 24 páginas passam dos 15 minutos.

Alguma sugestão de como converter um grande números de páginas num tempo tolerável ?
Abaixo exemplo de como estou utilizando.

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;
try {
    ob_start();
    include dirname(__FILE__).'/res/exemple00.php';
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->output('exemple00.pdf');
} catch (Html2PdfException $e) {
    $html2pdf->clean();
    $formatter = new ExceptionFormatter($e);
    echo $formatter->getHtmlMessage();
}
```

Comment: Jovem, uma página demora quanto tempo no seu caso? Os dados são dinâmicos?

Comment: 24 páginas geradas dinamicamente demora em média 15 minutos